# How to pass command-line arguments to main class in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle

I am creating simple Java class and I would like to create out-of-the-box launcher by using gradle.

So I want to be able to run Java program via gradle:

`gradlew clean run These are my command line arguments` where `These are my command line arguments` are passed directly to my `public static void main(String... args)` method.

I am using the `apply plugin: "application"` which gives me the `run` task. But when I am running this 'as is' I've got:

`* What went wrong:
Task 'These' not found in root project 'question1'. Some candidates are: 'test'.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gradle interprets each argument not starting with a hyphen (`-`) as task name to define which tasks will be executed during the build. Since a task with the name `These` does not exist, the build fails.

You are using the Gradle Application Plugin, which, as you already stated, provides a `run` task. The [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) show, that the `run` task is of the type [`JavaExec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html). So, to apply your arguments, add them to the `run` task via `args`:

```
run {
    args 'These are my command line arguments'
}
```

To modify the arguments for each build without changing the `build.gradle` file, simply use project properties:

```
run {
    args findProperty('runArgs')
}
```

And call `gradle clean run -PrunArgs='These are my command line arguments'`

Comment: This approach works, but the problem it has is that the args *always* have to be present. If you do anything else (eg. `gradle tasks`) the operation fails with a `NullPointerException` and the error pointing to the above `args` line in `build.gradle`. Do you know of a way to avoid that?

Comment: And to answer my own question: `if (project.hasProperty('runArgs') { args findProperty('runArgs') }` will do it. Phew.