# Getting null value when trying to read environment specific data from serenity.conf

Tags: java, rest-assured, serenity-bdd

I am trying to configure different environment specific data in serenity.conf and trying to read them using EnvironmentVariables in my serenity bdd tests.I have below configuration in serenity.conf

```
environments {
    dev {
        restapi.baseurl = "https://dev.api.3stripes.io/"
    }
    stg {
        restapi.baseurl = "https://stg.api.3stripes.io/"
    }
    default {
        restapi.baseurl = "https://prod.api.3stripes.io/"
    }
}
```

I am trying to read this in my bdd steps like this

```
EnvironmentVariables objEnvVar = SystemEnvironmentVariables.createEnvironmentVariables();
String baseURI = objEnvVar.getProperty("restapi.baseurl");
```

I am running the tests using maven command :

```
mvn clean verify -Denvironment=dev
```

But am getting null value for **baseURI** string.Please let me know what needs to be changed here to read the value properly.

Answer (score 3):

The `serenity.conf` file has to be located in either `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources` for it to be loaded.

**You have to use the `EnvironmentSpecificConfiguration` class** to read the values.

```
private EnvironmentVariables env;

@Test
void testMethod() {
    String baseurl =  EnvironmentSpecificConfiguration.from(env).getProperty("restapi.baseurl");
    String basepath =  EnvironmentSpecificConfiguration.from(env).getProperty("restapi.basepath");
}
```

My `serenity.conf` file looks like:

```
environments {
    localhost {
        restapi.baseurl = "https://localhost:9001"
    }
    uat {
        restapi.baseurl = "https://uat.myco.com"
    }
    default {
        restapi.baseurl = "https://some.host.com"
    }
    all {
        restapi.basepath = "/path/to/api"
    }
}
```

And I can activate the configs by running:

```
./gradlew -Denvironment=localhost clean test
```

Comment: have you figured out a way to extract more than URL from this file? something like 

        `my.webservice.endpoint = "https://local.host/"
        my.companyID = "local"
        my.userId = "local02"
        my.password = "Local@1234"`

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR = Use System.getProperty("environment") in your build.gradle if using Gradle instead of Maven

I started with a serenity Template.  I expect it to just work with the command line.
It includes build.gradle which has a section called test

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I leveraged a Gradle variable called jvmArgs and then picked up the value from the command line

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    def parameter = '-Denvironment='
    def environment = System.getProperty('environment')
    jvmArgs (parameter+environment)
}
```

Sample environments file from Serenity https://johnfergusonsmart.com/environment-specific-configuration-in-serenity-bdd/.

Sample code from Serenity pulls the values

```
private EnvironmentVariables envVars;
@Given("{actor} is requesting api information with a valid token")
public void getsFhaCase(Actor actor) {
     String baseUrl =  EnvironmentSpecificConfiguration.from(envVars).getProperty("api.baseUrl");
```

Thanks to [How to pass args to JVM which runs tests with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435218/how-to-pass-args-to-jvm-which-runs-tests-with-gradle) ([Lukas Körfer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3950370/lukas-k%c3%b6rfer)) for the tip on jvmArgs.

Thanks to [How to give System property to my test via Gradle and -D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406265/how-to-give-system-property-to-my-test-via-gradle-and-d) ([Jeff Storey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/121993/jeff-storey)) for the tipoff on System.getProperty().

At one time I implemented with `-Penvironment=value` using findProperty() in Gradle.  Should you need that approach see [How to pass command-line arguments to main class in gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44216986/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-main-class-in-gradle) ([Drew MacInnis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1458771/drew-macinnis)) for the tipoff on findProperty.